# Duplicate content from www and non-www

Tags: htaccess

I am getting duplicate content issues because both www and non-www are being loaded.

My htaccess has the standard force https as all my other sites but it isn't working.

```
# START Force https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?geniusesforhire\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.geniusesforhire.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# END Force https
```

Could anything in Craft be causing this or is anything in Craft able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

2 options to avoid duplicate content:

- add a canonical tag to your HTML
- redirect non-www to www or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache redirect rule is only redirecting http -> https.

You also want a rule to redirect non-www hits to the www version.

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.geniusesforhire.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As [Matthias](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/36111/1016) mentions in his answer, I'd also put a `link` tag somewhere in the head of your Twig template. Assuming craft's `entry` variable is available:

```
{% if entry is defined %}<link rel="canonical" href="{{ entry.url }}">{% endif %}
```